# P vs. NP: a proof by contradiction from an assumption

Tags: polynomials, np-complete

Can someone explain to me this proof by contradiction?

[image]

Comment: We can only guess about what you don't understand unless you tell us.  Do you know what the polynomial hierarchy is?  Do you understand why P=NP would collapse it?

Comment: @KyleJones Not in great detail but basically yes, I do understand this. But I have problems with the last 2 lines of the proof: there is a set $S_d$ etc. ...

Comment: What text is this from?

Comment: @NoahSchweber It is from [this](http://93.174.95.29/main/452000/f05279c1ef3629cada6443274a53a432/Richard%20J.%20Lipton%20%28auth.%29%20-%20The%20P%3DNP%20Question%20and%20G%C3%B6del%E2%80%99s%20Lost%20Letter-Springer%20US%20%282010%29.pdf) book The P=NP Question and Gödel’s Lost Letter.

Comment: @user122424 Please do not link to illegal download sites (especially ones which auto-download the file in question)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As a notational point, I'll use $\mathsf{P}$-superscripts for levels of the polynomial hierarchy (e.g. "$\Sigma^\mathsf{P}_2$," etc.). The notation "$\Sigma_k$" is also used, but that clashes with the notation for the completely different arithmetical hierarchy.*

---

The key point is that if $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ then the polynomial hierarchy collapses *a lot*: everything in the polynomial hierarchy is in fact in $\mathsf{P}$. (See e.g. Theorem $3$ [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/complexity/f11/lecture8.pdf).)

With this in hand we can argue at first as follows:

- Suppose that some $c$ as in the hypothesis of the theorem exists, and additionally (towards a contradiction) that $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.
- Applying Ravi's theorem and noting that $\Sigma^P_2\subseteq \mathsf{P}$ (since $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$) we have that for any $d$ there is some $S_d\in\mathsf{P}$ requiring circuits of size $n^d$.
- But now consider any $d>c$ ...

Comment: What does Ravi's theorem say ?

Comment: @user122424 The quoted passage in your post states Ravi's theorem already: "Ravi's theorem proves that for any $d$ there is a set in [the] second level of the polynomial hierarchy that requires a circuit of size $n^d$ for all $n$." Presumably in the text you're using Ravi's theorem was already stated in a previous section.

Comment: Would "for **almost** all $n$" be more precise ? Which theorem from Ravi's [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01744432.pdf) is the corresponding one ?

Comment: @user122424 Yes, there's an implicit asymptotic modifier in claims like these; this is an admittedly annoying standard abuse of terminology. As to the theorem itself, Ravi's paper doesn't prove it in those terms; the circuit complexity phrasing came later. Doesn't your text introduce Ravi's theorem somewhere?

Comment: Please see this [link](http://93.174.95.29/main/452000/f05279c1ef3629cada6443274a53a432/Richard%20J.%20Lipton%20%28auth.%29%20-%20The%20P%3DNP%20Question%20and%20G%C3%B6del%E2%80%99s%20Lost%20Letter-Springer%20US%20%282010%29.pdf) here is the whole book. Can you find the reference ? I think that the reference is [74] on the page 231 which is exactly the reference in the comment above yours.

Comment: Oh I have just made again what you have complained about. Sorry. The apology is that we are using it for study purposes. And you have requested the source anyway.